# Featured Image Isn't showing with cropped, How to show it?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am trying to show feature image with cropping. My **functions.php** code is

```
add_theme_support('post-formats', array('post'));
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

add_image_size('post-image', 750, 400, true);
```

And my **index.php** code is

```
<img src="<?php $image =wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id
          ($post->ID), 'post-image' ); echo $image[0] ?>" alt="" />
```

How can i show my image in post with cropping. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Put this line in your function.php

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

and use this code for image
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}

Comment: what will be for img src

Comment: Not using img tag simply put this code  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); }